# Struts2 validation.xml and validate() method

Tags: validation, struts2

I've got a struts2 `validation.xml` file to do some simple validation, but I need a more complex validation that requires taking data from database and checking it.

I'm doing it using `validate()` method from `ActionSupport` and it works fine. I just don't understand why when page gets back from validation the jsp page shows that validation form validation.xml has its own `<ul>` tag, and validation from `validate()` method has another one. There is some way to combine both?

Comment: Are you seeing the same error message twice? Or what do you mean by "has its own tag"?

Comment: Every field use a collection of errors. You can do whatever you want with that collection.

Comment: By "has its own tag" I mean that in the html which user gets from a JSP has two <ul> tags, one with <li> elements for errors on fields inside validation.xml and another <ul> tag which has <li> elements with errors added from validate() method. I'd like to turn those two <ul> tags in just one.

Comment: @Luis: Show your JSP code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can forgo the s:fielderror (or what ever error tag you're using) and use plain OGNL if you wish. Look at ActionSupport and you'll see getFieldErrors(), handle as you would a Map of Collections. Same methods can be applied for other errors.